# A figure tikz does not appear. I want to position it

Tags: tikz-pgf

I do not manage to position my figure maclef.
It does not appear at all.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[xshift = 0.cm, yshift = 0.cm]
        \draw[fill = lightgray]  maclef; 
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want to put the figure of maclef, next to another figure, of a mailbox.
The figure of maclef is defined by :

\newcommand{\maclef}[1][(x,y)]{% 1 optional parameter for options for the tikz picture

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm, scale = 0.5]

%\clip(-63.65625,-38.22000000000016) rectangle (71.66437500000004,28.30125000000011);

        \draw [shift={(6.9878812572759035,4.204062863795111)},line width=2.pt]  plot[domain=-0.6874558117651883:3.7890537974086786,variable=\t]({1.*0.6367477167910794*cos(\t r)+0.*0.6367477167910794*sin(\t r)},{0.*0.6367477167910794*cos(\t r)+1.*0.6367477167910794*sin(\t r)});

        \draw [line width=2.pt] (6.98,4.26) circle (0.2cm);

        \draw [line width=2.pt] (6.7,3.6)-- (6.7,1.86);

        \draw [line width=2.pt] (6.7,1.86)-- (7.28,1.84);

        \draw [line width=2.pt] (7.28,1.84)-- (7.1,2.18);

        \draw [line width=2.pt] (7.1,2.18)-- (7.32,2.42);

        \draw [line width=2.pt] (7.32,2.42)-- (7.1,2.72);

        \draw [line width=2.pt] (7.1,2.72)-- (7.4,3.);

        \draw [line width=2.pt] (7.4,3.)-- (7.18,3.42);

        \draw [line width=2.pt] (7.18,3.42)-- (7.587100914810832,3.9886946747272374);

        \draw [line width=2.pt] (6.7,3.6)-- (6.418409541646128,3.919195140217425);

    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Comment: sorry the code was sent without returns

Comment: Why should the 6 letters `maclef` become an image?  As it is, TikZ doesn't know what to do with the `m`, and issues an error that you must fix before worrying about a figure not appearing.  (And see https://tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting for code formatting - if you only post text, it's treated like in html p tags.)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What should the output of the above code look like? Maybe you should explain a bit what you want to achieve as this is not clear from your question.

Comment: As @Teepeemm says, your syntax is wrong. What are you trying to do? If you have a file called `maclef` (pdf? png? jpg?) you will need an `\incudegraphics` somewhere, either outside of TikZ where normal text would be or inside TikZ inside a node (where normal text would go), say `\node {\includegraphics{maclef}};`.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure what you are eventually aiming at, but it looks that what you're after is a `\pic`. You should not nest `tikzpicture`s.

```
\documentclass[border=19pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    maclef/.pic={
        \begin{scope}[
            line width=2pt,
            line cap=round,
            line join=round,
            scale = 0.5,
            pic actions
        ]
        
            \draw[shift={(6.9878812572759035,4.204062863795111)}] 
                plot[domain=-0.6874558117651883:3.7890537974086786, variable=\t]
                ({1.*0.6367477167910794*cos(\t r)+0.*0.6367477167910794*sin(\t r)},
                 {0.*0.6367477167910794*cos(\t r)+1.*0.6367477167910794*sin(\t r)});
        
            \draw
                (6.98,4.26) circle (0.2cm)
                (6.7,3.6) -- (6.7,1.86)
                (6.7,1.86) -- (7.28,1.84)
                (7.28,1.84) -- (7.1,2.18)
                (7.1,2.18) -- (7.32,2.42)
                (7.32,2.42) -- (7.1,2.72)
                (7.1,2.72) -- (7.4,3)
                (7.4,3) -- (7.18,3.42)
                (7.18,3.42) -- (7.587100914810832,3.9886946747272374)
                (6.7,3.6) -- (6.418409541646128,3.919195140217425);
        \end{scope}
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

        \pic[draw=lightgray] {maclef}; 

        \pic[draw=red] at (2,0) {maclef}; 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As you can see, I didn't do much to your code, only cleaned it up a bit. The code for the `\pic` is essentially the code of your command. The `scope` is to apply the Ti*k*Z keys to the code.

Comment: Thank you very much. It does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: And sorry, I'm a beginner in tikz, as you can see ...

Comment: @Massenet There's no reason to feel sorry. Ti*k*Z is a very complex package and it takes some time to understand how it works. If you need more information about `\pic`s and Ti*k*Z in general, I can suggest the [online manual](https://tikz.dev) to the package. It is huge, but it also contains some nice tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for this advice, I will have a look